# Cannot Debug in VS2017 with Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution with 4 projects, three of them are C++, and one is C#. I am trying to debug the C# one, but am unable to. Every single time I try, I get an error that says

> Unable to start debugging. check your debugger settings by opening project properties and navigating to 'Configuration Properties -->Debugging'

Configuration is Debug, and the Platform is Any CPU. I am not debugging on a remote machine.

I have VS2017 installed on Windows 10.

Comment: Are the C++ programs 32bit and is your OS 64 bit?  Does the C# project use the C++ ones, possibly as DLLs?

Comment: To debug your problem, and to start with you can add your projects one by one to the solution and see if each is debuggable on its own.

Comment: The C++ programs are 32bit, and my OS is 64 bit. The C# project doesn't use C++ ones.

Comment: Have you tried closing all instances of Visual Studio and re-opening the solution? Or running Visual Studio as administrator? Deleted all `bin` and `obj` folders and then doing a rebuild solution?

Comment: @rippo, Maybe you could just setup the correct project as the start up project firstly before you really debug your app. Like leo's suggestion, the error would be related to the VC++, like the Directory: $(ProjectDir). Please also clean the cache: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\xxx\ComponentModelCache

Answer (score 5):

> Cannot Debug in VS2017 with Windows 10

According to the error message:

> check your debugger settings by opening project properties and **navigating to 'Configuration Properties -->Debugging'**

This should be the debuger settings for C++ project rather than C# project:

C++:

[image]

C#:

[image]

**So**, first, you should **make sure your StartUp Project is C# project**. And for the C++ project, you can create a new blank C++ project, then compare the debugger settings of the problematic project with the settings of the new project.

Hope this helps.